# Changing text in shape textbox but getting "index into the specified collection is out of bounds" error

Tags: excel

I am trying to change the text in named shape text boxes that are copied from another sheet and retain the same name, but I keep getting the error

> -2147024809 index into the specified collection is out of bounds

I've tried changing the names, using standard text boxes, and changing the text on the original sheet but nothing is working

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A21:D37").Copy      
Worksheets("Sheet1").Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A9")
```

'This is the code that copies what i need from the other sheet that brings the shape text boxes with it

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes(shapeTextBox1).TextFrame.Characters.Text = stringVariable
```

'it throws the error on this line of code

it should show up as the string value i have set up for `stringVariable` but it is giving me the error code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to change the text in the shape text box directly, i linked each textbox to a cell and had the vba code change that

NOTE: I did have to lock the link to the cell or it would try to take that same cell address of the page i was pasting it to (='Sheet1'!$A$1)